# Looking for the Hans Hanson (Hansson, Hansen) family who came to North America via Quebec in 1870

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, canada, quebec, sweden

I have tracked the Hanson family (Hanna, Hans, Jens, infant) from Gothenburg to Hull to Liverpool to Quebec (aboard the Allan Line SS Germany) but her husband and other son (Hans and Nils) were not with them. It's possible they were on a different ship direct from Gothenburg to Quebec (SS Josephine) or perhaps sailed a year earlier in 1869. I have gotten assistance from Swedish Genealogists to track down Hanna and her sons but have lost the trail of husband Hans and other son Nils. Their Swedish departure contract number is 149400.

I am writing a book on this family and trying up loose ends!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find an immigration record for Hans and Nils.

Comment: Hi Scott, do you have an approximate age for Nils? If he was over the age of ~14, then it would make sense for him to go in advance with his father. I have seen in my own family a lot of times the father came over first, possibly with an older son or two, and then later on the wife and young children followed after.

Comment: Also, if you can find him in the 1900 census, that one gives a year of immigration, which may or may not be accurate, but at least it's a place to start.

Comment: There is an 1880 family in Nebraska with similar names ... also a 1900 family in Nebraska, with a Nils who came over in 1883. [BAC-LAC](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/) has a Nils Hanson who came to Quebec City in 1883 with a Hans who appears to be the same age (brother, not father?). Anyway I understand the frustration since it is a common name! Take these as starting places to investigate, don't just accept them as your family. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  This question might attract better answers if you phrased it as a methodology question instead of as a general query. "Looking for any information" is too vague to attract good answers.  https://www.theancestorhunt.com/blog/crafting-an-irresistible-research-question

Answer (score -1):

Their departure contract number is 149400 from Saxtorp 7, Saxtorp, Skane. Hoping to learn if they travelled together ... I did find them all in an 1870 census of Saunders County, Nebraska, all give 1870 as immigration year. Curious that all their names are on the departure contract but I can't find them all together in the passenger list. Would they have possibly travelled with a larger group (possibly a church group)? Nils was 3 years old at the time.

Comment: Hi Scott.  You should edit this into your question, rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try - I posted the information I already have so I wouldn't waste anyone's time and get repeat answers.